# WebAPI not returning CD Info from TOC

Tags: gracenote

I originally sent this via the support email address and was directed to post it here. I did get some information back about the issue will post below.

I am evaluating the WebAPI for recognizing TOC information from Audio CDs. I have hit an issue where the WebAPI doesn't return any data for a few CD's. I have checked the CD's with other sources and the TOC seems valid.

Here is an example TOC that doesn't return the correct data:
150 13618 27701 46018 60995 68989 82330 88600 102597 110046 130091 144691 160769 167288 175151

That should return Enya - the Celts.

I have a few other discs that don't return the required information and if you require them I'd be happy to collate the list and send them over to you.

Thanks

Antoine Kurukchi

Comment: Response in the email:   FYI-The TOC you included doesn't contain enough numbers for the The Celts by Enya.  It is short by 6 digits.  That might be affecting what you are working on.

Comment: I checked the number of tracks and it is correct. The only thing I can think of is that it requires the lba of the end of the last track. I had a quick look at the documentation but it doesn't appear to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

As the response you got through the email, you need another 6 digits at the end of the TOC. It either indicates the length of the album or the end of the last track. So you will need **number-of-tracks plus one** numbers in a TOC. (In your example, you need 16 numbers in TOC - 15 tracks + 1 )
How I get the 16th TOC number using your example: use the length of the last track and the 15th TOC to estimate the 16th number. Gracenote can recognize it even if it's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find the opposite is true.

The FreeDB works properly with Numberof tracks and playtime at the end

This example works with Freedb/CDDB
8 187 22502 39067 65425 101542 122447 143777 159945 2560

For the Same CD, this works with Gracenote
187 22502 39067 65425 101542 122447 143777 159945